# JSON body for putting a new item in table in AWS DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to do a HTTP POST to put an item into a DynamoDB table (called "policy")

I am struggling to get the correct format. The item only has one key which is "PolicyNumber" and an additional item I am adding called 'Name'

My JSON is as follows:-

```
{\"TableName\":\"Policy\",\"Item\":
{\"PolicyNumber\":\"S\":\"10001\"},\"Name\":{\"S\":\"Test10001\"}}}
```

I get an error as follows (all one string obviously):-

```
{
"statusCode": "400",
"body": "One or more parameter values were invalid: Type mismatch for key 
PolicyNumber expected: S actual: M",
"headers": {
"Content-Type": "application/json"
}
}
```

If I run a GET to list items already in there I get the following response (these items added through console):-

```
{
"statusCode": "200",
"body": "{\"Items\":[{\"PolicyNumber\":\"12345\",\"Name\":\"Fred\"},{\"PolicyNumber\":\"78787\",\"Name\":\"Bill\"}],\"Count\":2,\"ScannedCount\":2}"
,
"headers": {
"Content-Type": "application/json"
}
```

}

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:

- Solution:

Replace `{ "S": "10001" }` by `"10001"` and 
`{ "S": "Test10001" }` by `"Test10001"`

The type is implicit.

- Old Answer:

There is a missing `{` after `PolicyNumber`. You should have this JSON:

```
{ "TableName": "Policy",
  "Item": {
     "PolicyNumber": { "S": "10001" },
     "Name": { "S": "Test10001" }
  }
}
```

Read more about [AWS DynamoDB PutItem here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html#putItem-property).

Comment: Thansk for suggestion. I get the same error when using the JSON to match your suggestion:-       { \"TableName\": \"Policy\",\"Item\": {\"PolicyNumber\": { \"S\": \"10001\" },\"Name\": { \"S\": \"Test10001\"}}}

Comment: Try to replace `{ "S": "10001" }` by `"10001"` and `{ "S": "Test10001" }` by `"Test10001"`.

Comment: Yes - that worked - thanks. Although doesn't seem to match any of the documentation around passing in the data type etc - slightly confused by that.

Comment: Great. I've edited the answer. Should you find it ok, feel free to accept it, thus the next person which see the question will trust the solution. Thanks.

Comment: Updated answer solved the issue - just with a slight outstanding concern on why it doesn't match my understanding from the docs etc!